# Is there a formula that I can use to come up with a one score rating for my delivery drivers?

Tags: analysis, statistics, time-series, related-rates

I have a delivery company and have multiple drivers who work for me. The way it works is this:

- I get delivery offers (in the form of dollars) from dozens of clients all day long
- I can either accept or decline these offers
- I decide which ones to accept or decline by considering the logistics of where it’s going,
  how much is being offered for that delivery, and what other deliveries I may or may not have already committed to.

In short, I am paid “per delivery” from these clients. The item count is almost always not an issue, so I do not track item count and it’s mostly irrelevant to how I manage this business.

As such, it’s in my best interest to keep hours and miles down as low as possible, orders as high as possible, while accepting the highest paying delivery offers to to maximize my profits.

I keep detailed records with the following base statistics to see how good my drivers are doing. These are all **per day & per driver**. I generate these on weekly reports:

**Base stats:**
 1. Total Miles
 2. Total hours
 3. Total orders completed
 4. Total Gross revenue

Using those base stats, I have 6 stats that I generate, 3 of which are:

**Generated stats A:**
 1. miles per hour
 2. orders per hour
 3. gross revenue per order

...but the 3 most important stats that I study on my weekly reports to really base how good my drivers are doing are these last 3:

**Generated stats B:**
 4. Gross revenue per hour
 5. Gross revenue per mile
 6. Daily Percentage of gross revenue *(7 days adding up to 100%, how much each day was responsible for generating the total gross revenue that week)*.

My question is this: **is there a formula that I can use that incorporates these statistics ultimately generating 1 single score, to gauge how well each driver did that day?** Ideally the last 3 stats above numbered 4-6 would be required in this formula, but if stats 1-3 are also used, that would be optional.

Comment: There are multitudes of formulas that combine these. The simplest are to just look at one and ignore the others. The problem is pick a formula that is *most useful*. And that is a managerial problem, not a mathematical one. And for that this is the wrong forum. One thing I note is that these statistics appear to influenced by *your* actions far more heavily than your drivers. If you want to evaluate your drivers, you need to collect statistics based on their actions, not yours.

Comment: You’re right, so I’d like to evaluate my actions. If there are a multitude of formulas, what is an example of one? @<paul Sinclair>

Comment: I already mentioned three. calling (4) = $H$, (5) = $M$, (6) = $P$, then each of $H$, $M$ and $P$ by itself is a formula reducing your three scores to one (by ignoring the other two). Or you could just add them together, or multiply each by scaling factors, and add the results together. Or you could multiply them togheher, or take the sine of one, the square root of another and the natural logarithm of the third and add those together. Formulas that reduce your three scores to one are a dime-a-dozen. Most are worthless. Determining what is useful is a managerial issue, not mathematical.